# Why does low ionospheric conductance result in an increase in electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, astrophysics, plasma-physics

So [Anderson et al](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/92JA01975) proposed a model to explain the production of Sub Auroral Ion Drifts. In the paper they talk about how the decrease in ionospheric conductance results in an increase in the electric field, but why is this so?

I understand that decrease in conductance is an increase in resistivity. By Ohm's law $V = IR$ and thus $V$ increases, but since $E = -\displaystyle\frac{dV}{dx}$ shouldn't $E$ decrease if conductance decreases ?

Comment: It could be helpful if you quote text from the paper so we know which part you are talking about. Research papers are not easy to simply go through. Also, assuming Ohm's law is applicable in the situation, are you sure that the authors aren't talking about merely the magnitude of the electric field and not the direction? And finally, I am quite sure that the astrophysics tag is not applicable here. I'll leave this to the experienced users to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the paper they talk about how the decrease in ionospheric conductance results in an increase in the electric field, but why is this so?

This just results from [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) and some assumptions about the system.  The generalized Ohm's law can be written as:
$$
\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B} \approx \frac{ \mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B} }{ n \ e } - \frac{ \nabla}{ n \ e } \cdot \left( \mathcal{P}_{e} + \frac{ m_{e} }{ m_{i} } \mathcal{P}_{i} \right) + \eta \ \mathbf{j} + \frac{ m_{e} }{ n \ e^{2} } \frac{ d \mathbf{j} }{ d t } \tag{0}
$$
where $\mathbf{j}$ is the total current density, $n$ is the total number density (assuming *quasi-neutrality*, i.e., $n_{e} = n_{i}$), $e$ is the fundamental charge, $\mathcal{P}_{s}$ is the pressure tensor of species $s$, $m_{s}$ is the mass of species $s$ ($s$ can be $e$ for electron or $i$ for ion), and $\eta$ is the scalar electrical [resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) (see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/438272/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363523/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/261223/59023 for more on Ohm's law and conductivities).  Typically, many of these terms are small enough to be negligible and one can approximate the electric field as:
$$
\mathbf{E} \approx \eta \ \mathbf{j} \tag{1}
$$
Note that $\eta^{-1} = \sigma$ which is the electrical conductivity.  So for situations where the current is held constant but $\sigma$($\eta$) decreases(increases), the magnitude of $\mathbf{E}$ must increase accordingly.  Situations like this can arise when there's a constant input source for the current from an external driver.

As an aside, one generally does not drop several of the terms I ignored here in generalized Ohm's law for the ionosphere because they are not always negligible in this region.  I merely did so to help simplify the point.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably this:

To sustain a field requires a potential difference between two points. if the path between those two points is conductive, a small current will flow between them, the potential difference gets bled away, and the strength of the field diminishes. If the conductance between them is low, no current will flow, the charge imbalance will be sustained, and the strength of the field is not diminished.